# Configure MQ Call for local testing Jetty

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I was successful in making MQ call on my websphere server. But I am having hard time to make the same work on local jetty server. I am not even bale to start my server locally because of jms error.

I have two jndi name configured on websphere server as:

ConnectionFactory- jms/connectionFactory

Queue- jms/cardAcquireQueue

Below is code for bean entry:-

```
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> 
    <property name="connectionFactory">
         <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jms/connectionFactory"/>
    </property> 
    <property name="defaultDestinationName"> 
         <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jms/cardAcquireQueue"/> 
    </property>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" /> 
</bean>
```

The above works fine on server. But for jetty I have following code in jetty:-

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
     <Arg></Arg>
     <Arg>jms/connectionFactory</Arg>
     <Arg>
        <New class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <Arg>vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false</Arg>
        </New>
     </Arg>
   </New>

   <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
     <Arg></Arg>
     <Arg>jms/cardAcquireQueue</Arg>
     <Arg>
       ------I dont know What needs to be done here -----
     </Arg>
   </New>
</Configure>
```

I am not getting error from jms/ConnectionFactory but with jms/cardAcquireQueue I get returned null error.

Can you help how to configure jndi name for jms queue.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I have the same question.

Comment: I have the same question here, so interested to know how this was solved.